# Multiple linear regression model

Tags: r

Can anyone please help me to understand the difference between using the asterisk and the plus signs in multiple linear regression model? If I want to fit this model

```
model<-lm(continuous variable ~ Covariate SEX+ Covariate RACE+ Factor gene* Factor SNP, 
    data= mydata)
```

is using the plus sign and the asterisk at the same time correct? I'm interested at looking the impact of factor gene and factor SNP on the continuous variable and I’m controlling for sex and race as co-variates in this study.

Also, I have another question please, if I'm fitting nearly over 100 model should I check for model assumption for each model that I fitted?

Comment: "*" in a formula represents an interaction between the two independent variables. Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56784/how-to-interpret-the-interaction-term-in-lm-formula-in-r

Comment: You might find this link useful, see Wilkinson Rogers Notation https://r4ds.had.co.nz/model-basics.html#formulas-and-model-families

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is for crossing, (ie, `y~a*b` is equivalent to `y~a+b+a:b`)

`continuous variable ~ Covariate SEX+ Covariate RACE+ Factor gene* Factor SNP`

is, therefore, equivalent to

`continuous variable ~ Covariate SEX+ Covariate RACE+ Factor gene + Factor SNP + Factor gene:Factor SNP`

What you're doing is totally fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification, its appreciated.